# How to find more clever algorithm to check pairs of primes to see if paired they produce another prime?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes, mathematical-optimization

I am stuck on [Project Euler question 60](https://projecteuler.net/problem=60). I know it is advised not too ask questions or find answers online about it, but otherwise I cannot find the motivation to continue. So I hope to find some help here which can make me go forward.

So long for the disclaimer, the question I have is programmatic in nature. The problem is to

> Find the lowest sum for a set of five primes for which any two primes concatenate to produce another prime.

Now my idea was to use the naive way and just find all sets of five primes up to a certain `n`th prime (in the question it is given that 673 is the highest value to go up to to find four primes with this property so I decided to go up to 800th prime first), then find all possible pairs, and just check if we can find one where all possible pairs are not prime:

```
require 'prime'

def concat a, b

  val_arr = (a.to_s + b.to_s).scan(/\d/).map { |s| s.to_i }
  retval = 0
  factor = 1

  until val_arr.empty? 
    retval += val_arr.pop * factor
    factor *= 10
  end

  retval

end

primes = Prime.take(800) # Arbitrary large, but not too large, value

prime_sets = p primes.combination(5).to_a
prime_duos = primes.permutation(2).to_a # <= takes too long

prime_sets.each do |set| 
  puts set.reduce(:+) if set.permutation(2).all? { |duo| (concat duo.first, duo.last).prime? }
end
```

`prime_duos` method seems to never stop. Even with lower values (up to 100 primes) it takes ages.

How can I make a more clever algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your efficiency problem is that you are attempting to find target prime numbers by construction of a very large set of possibilities and filtering by results. The set of all building blocks and their combinations is much larger than the available targets, so you spend a huge amount of time constructing the combinations, only to filter almost all of them out.

It makes more sense to start the work from a set of possible target "combined" prime numbers. You know that these target numbers must decompose into two smaller primes. A strategy based on that would work loosely as follows:

- Generate a list of primes up to some target number - one million (or perhaps 10 million). This can be done pretty quickly, e.g. `Prime.take(75000)`
- Use that list to generate split (opposite of concatenate) arrays of allowed pairs. From `Prime.take(75000)` there are 23494 such pairs, with 7216 unique primes and that list can be generated in a few seconds - contrast that with the number of items you were trying to work with in your original code.
- Obviously don't take that list of 7216 primes and use it directly, you'd be back where you started. Instead, use the list of pairs you generated to create an efficient search for a group of 5 which satisfies your constraints. Think of the properties that such a group of 5 would have that you could test using the list of valid pairs.

I hope that gives you enough to start again. I am not going to supply the remainder of this solution or any Ruby code, since I think it reduces the value of the Euler challenge.

Comment: I can now create the pairs. I'm pondering about step 3. My idea would be to start with one pair, check if both exist in another pair and use that other pair to continue the search. Discard if we do not reach four. If we have the list of fours we can search for a new prime that has pairs with all four in the list and add those. Then we have a list of fives. Could you please provide a bit more information on step 3?

Comment: Essentially that is correct, but remember that the numbers have to able to work in *any* combination. So every time you add a new prime to the group, it has to be able to pair up with all the numbers you have so far. Further, if you construct a hash keyed by a starting prime with all the other primes it can pair with, then you can immediately exclude picking any prime with less than four potential partners (because there is no way it could end up in the final group) . That should make your search space much smaller again.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's the permutations that are your problem. On my computer, those execute in well less than 1/10th of a second.

Now, the combinations, OTOH, that's a different question. I mean, just forget about how long it takes for them be *computed*. Just look at how many there are: 800 choose 5 with repetition, that's 2764949600160 permutations. Even if you had a 5GHz CPU, and could compute one permutation at every clock cycle, it would still take 9 minutes and 12 seconds to compute.

On a 32 bit system, a Ruby `Fixnum` takes 4 Bytes, on a 64 bit system, it's 8. The `Array` you are storing those permutations in would need over 10 TB of RAM (20 TB on a 64 bit system).

Plus, you are printing all those numbers out. The console is *slow*. Really S-L-O-W. I think you can probably print not more than one line per millisecond. This will take you about 88 years to print.

So, in summary: you are using a computation that will probably take *hours* to finish, store the results in a 20 TB array, and then print it out … and you do all of that before your *actual* algorithm even starts.

Comment: `.combination` does not have repetitions, so it's "800 choose 5 *without* repetition" - you got the number right IMO, so it's just a typo? You also seem to mix permutation/combination up in that paragraph, which in a normal English sentence I'd get what you mean, but you are contrasting `.combination` versus `.permutation` here. Oh, and you also don't answer the OP's question, but do point out an important misunderstanding in it

Comment: A the `p` was still there for debugging purposes. Thanks for putting the calculation into perspective!